# Method with its argument and using dictionary in a class

Tags: python, dictionary, methods, pytorch, arguments

```
class Trainer():
  def __init__(self,param):
        ..........
        optimizer_target = getattr(optim, param['optimizer'])(net.parameters(), lr = param['learning_rate'])

     def train(epoch):
        .......... 

     def test(self, epoch):
        ..........

  def objective(self,train):
     
     params = {}
     model = Trainer(params)
     accuracy = model.test(trial)
      
     return accuracy 

if __name__ == '__main__':
    study = optuna.create_study(direction="maximize")
    study.optimize(objective)
```

when I call this objective function in main() it gives me different errors.No matter if I call this function like this it gives me the error

```
study.optimize(lambda trial: Trainer.objective(trial))
```

If I design it without the class Trainer it gives me the error. Kindly suggest how to call the dictionary of objective class and calling objective function in main()

Current error is

> study.optimize(lambda trial: Trainer.objective(trial))
> TypeError: objective() missing 1 required positional argument: 'trial'

Comment: You need to post the errors too. There can be many different problems.

Comment: study.optimize(lambda trial: Trainer.objective(trial))
TypeError: objective() missing 1 required positional argument: 'trial'

Comment: Please Post errors in your question and not in comments section.

Answer (score 0):

you should either instantiate your class, or define objective as @classmethod. For example:

```
class Trainer():
     def __init__(self,param):
        ..........
        optimizer_target = getattr(optim, param['optimizer'])(net.parameters(), lr = param['learning_rate'])

     def train(epoch):
        .......... 

     def test(self, epoch):
        ..........
     @classmethod
     def objective(self,train):
        params = {}

if __name__ == '__main__':
    study = optuna.create_study(direction="maximize")
    study.optimize(objective)
```

See classmethod (https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#classmethod) in python documentation.

Comment: Thank you so much for your recommendation. Your comment really helped me a lot to configure the error.

Comment: I have another question how can I do the same thing without a class Trainer. I have a big project which has multiple functions for custom methods and dataset and I cannot introduce a class in that project

Comment: The test() function which is I am calling in the objective function is giving an error 
'Trainer' object has no attribute 'test'

Comment: it is hard to say without a code. Maybe you could ask another question?